# Android New layout wants to replace the old

Tags: android

I'm new to android. When I try to create a new (landscape) layout in `layout-land folder`, it says:

> do you want to OVERWRITE the file res/layout/main.xml

Why does it want to REPLACE another layout? In eclipse, I right click the layout-land folder and choose New -> Others -> XML layout file. But it wants to replace this with my original layout file. How come? Though I used the same name for landscape layout as main.xml but I know that shouldnt conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a new layout you should give another name than main.xml, because it already exists.

Comment: but I read somewhere that in android we can use same resource name as it lies in different folder, maybe I m wrong

Comment: In different folders it is possible. I thought you are using the same folder. There may be some other problems present.

Answer (score 0):

what eclipse writes contradicts what you claim you try to do .

it talks about "layout" folder , and you talk about "layout-land" folder.

are you sure you put the file in the correct place?

anyway , your assumption is correct : you can put the same name in multiple places , adn it's a very common solution to handle multiple configurations (using what is called "qualifiers" ) .

more info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) .

Answer (score 0):

Did you place your folder as res/layout-normal-land?

Read this link for reference - http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html